# Can No Longer Drill Down to Subfolders in Wine

Tags: wine, paths

Some Windows applications such as Notebook++ that require access to files seem unable to open some subfolders. For example, I want to open `/var/www/html/` and whether I use `C:` or `Z:`, there is no + next to `/var/` and it won't open. Some folders do have the + but most do not. It WAS working until a few days ago and seems to have suddenly stopped so any ideas how to fix it?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 with all updates and Wine 5.0.3. I was running Wine 5.0.2 when the problem started yesterday and had hoped that an update would fixed it but it did not. The last time Wine broke I had to remove and reinstall it (meaning that all applications had to be reinstalled too) and I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: As soon as I posted, after two days of working on it, it seems to have started working again! It has been intermittent for quite a while though so clearly something is amiss.

Comment: Well, it's doing it again! Any ideas what to do or where to look for a repair?